# Harry Potter after Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, hermione-granger, ron-weasley

After Hogwarts, Harry and Ginny have children, but from what I remember, it doesn't mention what he does for a living, nor does it mention what Ron and Hermione do.

At one point, I distinctly remember Harry wanting to be an Auror, but what exactly does he do there, and do Hermione and Ron do the same thing?

EDIT: The question was answered, and not a duplicate. The question marked as duplicate asks for Ginny's profession, and is answered by the person with Harry's profession. I mentioned Ron and Hermione and wanted to know the specifics on the main 3's jobs.

Comment: Yes, Harry does become an Auror. This is stated in the epilogue to the last book, I believe.

Comment: There's a wee new play on in London that does a fair job of answering this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JKR revealed this in a [2007 interview](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0729-dateline-vieira.html) on the Today Show.

Harry and Ron work at the Auror Deparment at the Ministry of Magic, where Harry is the head of the department. Hermione is in some high ranking position in the Department for Magical Law Enforcement.

> JKR: **Harry and Ron utterly revolutionized the Auror Department in-- at the Ministry of Magic.** So they-- I mean, they are now the consummate-- they are experts. It doesn't matter how old they are or what else they've done. So Harry and Ron lead the way in recreating the new Auror Department. And by the time-- 19 years later -- **I would imagine that Harry is heading up that department,** which is not corrupt in any way. It's-- it's a really good place to be. **And Hermione ... I think she's now pretty high up in the Department for Magical Law Enforcement.** Where I would imagine that her brainpower and-- and her knowledge of how the dark arts operate would really give her a-- you know, a sound grounding. So they're all at the ministry but this is a very new ministry. They made a new world.

A more recent article on Pottermore ([transcribed version](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:Gcheung28/New_Rita_Skeeter_Article_from_J.K._Rowling_on_Pottermore)) clarified (and slightly changed) this further.

Harry is still an auror (or at least associated with the position enough to be referred to as one).

> About to turn 34, there are a couple of threads of silver in the famous Auror’s black hair, but he continues to wear the distinctive round glasses that some might say are better suited to a style-deficient twelve-year-old.

Ron became an auror, but left the job two years later to become a co-manager at Weasley's Wizard Wheezes.

> In the immediate aftermath of the battle Weasley, whose famous ginger hair appears to be thinning slightly, entered into employment with the Ministry of Magic alongside Potter, but left only two years later to co-manage the highly successful wizarding joke emporium Weasleys’ Wizard Wheezes.

Hermione is at the Department of Magical Law Enforcement, poised for promotion.

> After a meteoric rise to Deputy Head of the Department of Magical Law Enforcement, she is now tipped to go even higher within the Ministry, and is also mother to son, Hugo, and daughter, Rose.

Comment: I expected as much, but it's a lot different than I imagined. The books allude to Harry sort of being an Auror, but this takes their jobs to a whole new level in terms of what they actually do there.

Comment: Well, they presumably had to become aurors first before being put in charge of the whole thing. JKR is talking about where they are 19 years later.

Comment: It seems like the Aurors would work for the DMLE. Does that make Hermione Ron and Harry's boss?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai - I never realised this, but you're absolutely right! Of course she's meant to have revolutionised the corrupt aspects of wizarding society from within first the Department For Magical Creatures (sorting out her SPEW issues) and then more widely in this one. But she must be their overall boss, absolutely!

Comment: It was inevitable, I suppose.

Comment: Hmm...this is an excellent answer, and the question that this one is marked as a duplicate of doesn't have an answer with this source in it. I was tempted to flag it for a move, but that question also asks about Ginny specifically, so this answer might need expansion to fit properly there.

Comment: Don't forget [This article](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/harrypotter/images/4/4e/Quidditch_World_Cup_Final_%28Evening_Prophet%29.png/revision/latest?cb=20151216030025)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Harry Potter wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/):

- **[Harry Potter](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter):**

> Head of Auror Office
>
> Part-time lecturer on Defence Against the Dark
>   Arts

- **[Ronald Weasley](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Ronald_Weasley):**

> Former: Auror
>
> Current: Weasleys' Wizard Wheezes co-manager

- **[Hermione Granger](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Hermione_Granger):**

> Department for the Regulation and Control of Magical Creatures
>   (formerly)
>
> Deputy Head of the Department of Magical Law Enforcement

Note: The info at the Harry Potter wikia is compiled from multiple sources including JKR's interviews and Pottermore.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the Wizard of the Month from [the old jkrowling.com](http://web.archive.org/web/20110514102401/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/wotm.cfm):

> ### Harry Potter (1980 - )
>
> The Boy Who Lived, only known survivor of the Avada Kedavra curse and conqueror of Lord Voldemort, also known as Tom Riddle. **Harry Potter joined the reshuffled Auror Department under Kingsley Shacklebolt at age 17, rising to become Head of said department in 2007.**